# Filter out date less than 90 days old

Tags: r, date, filter

I have a dateframe with over 500k rows I need to remove all the rows that the date is less than 90 days from the date the code is run( system date/time)

| Name | Date. |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | 16/07/20 |
| Dave | 10/04/21 |

Comment: Use `as.Date` to convert to a `Date`-class object, then filtering is as simple as numeric comparisons. Read the help docs on [`as.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) (and [`strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) for the `%`-codes), [`Sys.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.time.html), and [`subset`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html). And perhaps [`difftime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html).

Comment: Thanks very much will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
dat$Date. <- as.Date(dat$Date., format = "%d/%m/%y")
dat
#   Name      Date.
# 1  Tom 2020-07-16
# 2 Dave 2021-04-10
difftime(Sys.Date(), dat$Date., units = "days")
# Time differences in days
# [1] 481 213
subset(dat, difftime(Sys.Date(), Date., units = "days") > 300)
#   Name      Date.
# 1  Tom 2020-07-16
```

Your sample data doesn't demonstrate your "90 days", so I changed it to "300 days" to show the filtering effect.

Other ways:

```r
dat[difftime(Sys.Date(), dat$Date., units = "days") > 300,]
#   Name      Date.
# 1  Tom 2020-07-16

library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  filter(difftime(Sys.Date(), Date., units = "days") > 300)
#   Name      Date.
# 1  Tom 2020-07-16
```